# Cannot find module '../scss/Navbar.scss' or its corresponding type declarations. When I want to use sass file in typescript project

Tags: reactjs, sass, react-typescript

Im completely new to react typescript projects.

Im scaffolding a typescript project using this:

```
npx create-react-app test --template typescript
```

And then I setup a sass module succefylly and configure it to package.json file by:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "sass": "sass src/scss:src/css --watch --no-source-map"
  }
```

Everything is okay And all stuff are build but when I want to use a sass file :

```
import styles from "../scss/Navbar.scss"
```

this error occured:

```
 Cannot find module '../scss/Navbar.scss' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

The file is in there and sass file location address is completely correct but I cant solve this error,  please help me tnx.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is exactly the file name. (That is  a css module feature)

So instead of :

```
Navbar.scss
```

I should change to:

```
Navbar.module.scss
```